# Safe to change owner of OS X system folders?

Tags: osx, chmod, chown, privileges

I'm trying to get Homebrew to work. That program's diagnosis tool gives me these suggestions:

> You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc
>
> ...
>
> You should probably `chown` them:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/share/man/de
> /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
> ```

Because these directories are not writable. I haven't changed owner or group before. Right now the owner of etc is `root` and the group is `wheel`, my username is something else.

Is it safe to change the owner of these folders on OS X? I am concerned that my user won't have all the privileges of `root` and therefore other applications will bump into problems, although my account is an admin account.

Comment: *Generally* speaking (I do not know about Mac OS X specifically), /usr/local is *supposed* to be managed by the administrator, not the system. If you are building from source code or installing from some prepared package, it may be *easier* to set the installation prefix to something completely under your control (e.g. `~/homebrew`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the full error messages to make this question more searchable:

```
Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
```

That can also happen if those directories were created by an installer (like a MacTeX or ImageMagick installer) or by `sudo easy_install` or `sudo pip install`.

Changing the owners of those directories should be safe:

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/etc /usr/local/share/man/de{,/man1}
```

This shows files owned by root sorted by creation time:

```
find /usr/local/{etc,share/man} -user root -exec stat -f '%B %N' {} \; | sort
```